# different between embedding Clips into C and embedding Clips into C++

Tags: c++, c, clips

I have confused about the different between embedding Clips into C and C++.
I have succeed to embed Clips into C Program obeying the steps on the Advanced Programming Guide (Chapter 4.17)
Now, I want to embed Clips into a C++ Program, and I have some question.

```
.c.o :
    gcc -c -Wall  -Wundef -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wcast-qual \
        -Wcast-align -Winline -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls \
        -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs \
        -Wstrict-prototypes -Waggregate-return -Wno-implicit $<

clips : $(OBJS)
    gcc -o clips $(OBJS) -lm -ltermcap
```

OBJS represents the .o files.

1. When I embed Clips into C program, I use makefile download from the github(shown as above). It uses "gcc" wonder if I should change the "gcc" into "g++" and do some other change.
2. the source file is .c file and .h file , should I change them into .cpp file and .hpp file?
3. there also clipsmm on the sourceforge described as A C++ CLIPS Interface, I download and read it's doc, I don't quite understand it. Does it just provide some .hpp file or a totally new clips?
4. I have use the C functions offered in the Advanced Programming Guide， I don't know if I can use these function when embedding Clips into C++?

Some stupid questions
Thank you for any answer or idea.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that C++ is for the most part backwards compatible with C.

If the clips headers contain `extern "C"` for their function prototypes in C++, you can use it just the same as for C. Just include the header files, and link with the library/object files generated from the C source files.

Answer (score 0):

Section 1.2 in the Advanced Programming Guide has some notes on C++ compatibility:

> 1.2 C++ COMPATIBILITY
>
> The CLIPS source code can now be compiled using either an ANSI C or
>   C++ compiler. Minimally, non-ANSI C compilers must support full ANSI
>   style function prototypes and the void data type in order to compile
>   CLIPS. If you want to make CLIPS API calls from a C++ program, it is
>   usually easier to do the integration by compiling the CLIPS source
>   files as C++ files. This removes the need to make an extern "C"
>   declaration in your C++ program for the CLIPS APIs. Some programming
>   environments allow you to specify the whether a file should be
>   compiled as C or C++ code based on the file extension. Other
>   environments allow you to explicitly specify which compiler to use
>   regardless of the extension (e.g. in gcc the option “-x c++” will
>   compile .c files as C++ files). In some environments, the same
>   compiler is used to compile both C and C++ programs and the compiler
>   uses the file extension to determine whether the file should be
>   compiled as a C or C++ program. In this situation, changing the .c
>   extension of the CLIPS source files to .cpp usually allows the source
>   to be compiled as a C++ program.

Rather than changing the file extensions, I'd suggest using the "-x c++" option with gcc for the .c files in your makefile. You can use g++ with your c++ source files. When you compile the source files in this manner, you can invoke the functions documented in the APG from your C or C++ code directly without the need for wrapping the function prototypes with extern "C".

I haven't used clipsmm, but it appears to be a set of C++ wrapper classes for the core CLIPS source code.